# Multiple checkbox in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I would like to ask, here's the scenario. I have this multiple checkbox but my problem is whenever I tick one checkbox, all of the 4 checkboxes are selected. And also why is it the value of checkbox is just true or false.Here's my checkbox:

```
<div className="checkbox">
    <label><Field name="investor_stage" component="input" type="checkbox" value="Seed" /> Seed</label>
</div>
<div className="checkbox">
    <label><Field name="investor_stage" component="input" type="checkbox" value="Early Stages" /> Early Stages</label>
</div>
<div className="checkbox">
    <label><Field name="investor_stage" component="input" type="checkbox" value="Formative Stages" /> Formative Stages</label>
</div>
<div className="checkbox">
    <label><Field name="investor_stage" component="input" type="checkbox" value=" Later Stages" /> Later Stages</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `ReduxForm` not supporting checkbox group. [This](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1037#issuecomment-243003954) might help you as workaround.

Comment: Hi @JyothiBabuAraja do you have an example how to implement it. I'm quite in new react :D. Thank you!

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/635#issuecomment-239056316) and an [example](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/635#issuecomment-270785911)

Comment: Yeah, I did try that but there's an error it looks like it is using the v5.5.3 of redux-form and I'm using v6.5.0

Comment: I am also on voyage of solving this problem :-), but yet to find a concrete answer.

Comment: @AftabNaveed I did solve the issue using this. check this link out
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1037#issuecomment-243003954

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883867/340142 it should be the chosen one.

Answer (score 19):

For people like me who are new to redux and react may find the original code mentioned [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1037#issuecomment-243003954) confusing. I modified and converted it to an ES6 class. I also Removed bootstrap, validation and made it easy to debug.

Here is the modified code

```
import React from 'react';

class CheckboxGroup extends React.Component {

    checkboxGroup() {
        let {label, required, options, input, meta} = this.props;

        return options.map((option, index) => {
            return (
            <div className="checkbox" key={index}>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           name={`${input.name}[${index}]`}
                           value={option.name}
                           checked={input.value.indexOf(option.name) !== -1}
                           onChange={(event) => {
                               const newValue = [...input.value];
                               if (event.target.checked) {
                                   newValue.push(option.name);
                               } else {
                                   newValue.splice(newValue.indexOf(option.name), 1);
                               }

                               return input.onChange(newValue);
                           }}/>
                    {option.name}
                </label>
            </div>)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.checkboxGroup()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default CheckboxGroup;
```

**Usage:**

```
let optionsList = [{id: 1, name: 'Optoin1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Option 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Option 3'}]     
<Field name="roles" component={CheckboxGroup} options={optionsList} />
```

Comment: Many thanks @aftab-naveed ! What does the optionsList object look like ? I try to implement it without success.

Comment: let optionList = {id: 1, name: 'Optoin1', id: 2, name: 'Option 2'}

Comment: Good but, touch event doesn't work for me, it is always false. After the first form submit, touched event start firing.

 const {options, name, input, meta: { touched, error }}  = this.props;
 const hasError = touched && error;

Comment: Works great; for some reason I had to make a change to `newValue`:  `const newValue = [...input.value] || []`

Comment: do i need jQuery for this?

Comment: No, you don't need jQuery for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please give different field names for each checkbox. (***name="investor_stage"***).The problem is all the field names are same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some style to @Aftab Naveed I wrapped my checkboxes in a label with these classnames instead and they ended up real pretty and easier clicked:

```html
<label key={option.name} className="form-check-label" style={ {"fontSize": "1.5em"} }>
          <input ... />
            <span>{option.name}</span>
          </label>
```

i did not use bootstrap, i think its a redux form thing with className "form-check-label"